# Why does Laravel separate table creation (migration) and model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I'm new to the framework, also new to the concept of ORM. If Eloquent maps a class to a DB table, shouldn't the table design also be handled by that class too?

For example, I want to create a `Person` class (or `Model`, to be precise), with `name` and `age` attributes. I have to create a table first, declare the 2 fields in a `persons` migration file, migrate it, and only after that can I create the `Person` model. I can create everything at once with '-mr', but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

In my opinion, the natural way is to create a `Person` class, and Laravel automagically creates a table for it, then maps them together. Why Laravel is not designed this way?

Another example might be SQLAlchemy. In this [introduction page](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html), SQLAlchemy also claims that "Separate mapping and class design" is an advantage feature.

Comment: Other ORMs that do automagically create tables for models are simply creating such migrations on the fly. This has the huge disadvantage of less control over the schema in my opinion, because you cannot simply restructure existing data you can with handwritten migrations.

Answer (score 1):

What I am going to give you may be an anecdotal evidence but it helped me to understand why the separation is there.

Earlier, I have done a project where there are two types of users both reside in the 'user' table. One type was customer; another type was worker. Both of them had fairly similar data like their name, address, email etc.

As I had only one table there was only one migration file. But there were two different models. One for customers and another for workers.

Although their data was similar yet their functions were very much different. A customer couldn't get hired. So, it would be silly to write get_hired() function in customer model (or user model). It belongs in the worker model. It made the code more manageable.

The separation of model and migration thus helps in this regard. Migration will let you play with the table structure but models with let you play with the actual data. Thus it helped making a more manageable code.

Technically, you can write every piece of logic in one single PHP file. But it is tough to manage it. Same logic is also applied here.